# Want to narrow data source based on custom post type categories in Visual composer (WPBakery)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, visual-composer

I have a custom post type of 'Cottages', with categories (1-bed, 2-bed, 3-bed).

I can get an element to show in Visual Composer with the following vc_map in my functions.php:

```
// Cottages List
if(function_exists('vc_map')){
   vc_map( array(
   "name" => __("My Cottages List", 'archi'),
   "base" => "cottageslist",
   "class" => "",
   "category" => 'My Elements',
   "icon" => "icon-rtcvc",
   "params" => array(      
      array(
         "type" => "textfield",
         "holder" => "div",
         "class" => "",
         "heading" => "Show how many cottages per page?",
         "param_name" => "number",
         "value" => "",
         "description" => __("Add Number -1 for show all post.", 'archi')
      ),  
    )
    ));
}'
```

Then, I know it displays with the following php/html code (that also staggers rows of feature-image, post content ... post content, feature-image)

```
// Cottages List start
add_shortcode('cottageslist','cottageslist_func');
function cottageslist_func($atts, $content = null){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'number'    =>      '',
    ), $atts));
    $number1 = (!empty($number) ? $number : 4);
    ob_start(); 
?>

    <?php
        $i = 0;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'cottages',
            'posts_per_page' => $number1,
        );
        $cottages = new WP_Query($args);
        if($cottages->have_posts()) : while($cottages->have_posts()) : $cottages->the_post(); $i++;
    ?>


        <section class="side-bg no-padding service-list" id="section-service-<?php echo esc_attr($i); ?>">

            <?php if ($i % 2 == 1) { ?>

            <div class="image-container col-md-5 pull-left" data-delay="0">
                <div class="background-image" style="background-image:url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>');"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="inner-padding">
                        <div data-wow-delay=".5s" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 wow fadeInRight">
                            <h3 class="id-color"><a class="" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            <div class="spacer-single"></div>
                            <a class="btn-line" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('Read More', 'archi') ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php }else{ ?>

            <div data-delay="0" class="image-container col-md-5 col-md-offset-7 pull-right right0">
                <div class="background-image" style="background-image:url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>');"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="inner-padding">
                        <div data-wow-delay=".5s" class="col-md-6 wow fadeInLeft">
                            <h3 class="id-color"><a class="" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            <div class="spacer-single"></div>
                            <a class="btn-line" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('Read More', 'archi') ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </section>            

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>  

<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}   
// Cottages List start
```

**Here's where I'm completely lost!:**

- I want to have the option in Visual Composer to narrow the data source based on one or more categories (bearing in mind they're custom post type categories).
- I think I'll need additional code in my second block (php/html) to ensure only the chosen categories are displayed.

Help! I've been doing the noob trick of cuting-n-pasting from whatever code I can find that might help, and after a day of this I'm still failing!

And yes, I know the VC Post Grid element will filter very well, but I don't like how on the front end those Post Grid blocks only load up a few seconds after the rest of the page has fully loaded.

Thanks
JD